# Can the total sum of geometric multiplicities be less than n for an nxn matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can the total sum of geometric multiplicities be less than $n$ for an $n \times n$ matrix?

I understand that the algebraic multiplicity bounds the geometric multiplicity, which leads me to think that the sum of the geometric multiplicity cannot be greater than $n$ as there are $n$ eigenvalues but I am unsure if the geometric multiplicity can be less than $n$.

Comment: Yes. The algebraic multiplicities always sum to $n$, and the geometric multiplicities will also sum to $n$ if and only if the matrix is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Try
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$